# not initialised at super.init swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm trying to create a dynamic cell where sometimes I would like the cell to show the last message and sometimes I don't want the label to be there.

I get an error saying `lastMsg` not initialized at `super.init`
here's my cell:

```
class mainChatCell: UITableViewCell {
    let imgUser = UIImageView()

    let labUserName : UILabel = {
        let lab = UILabel()
        lab.text = "emily"
        return lab
    }()

    let lastMsg : UILabel?

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        imgUser.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        imgUser.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        imgUser.clipsToBounds = true
        imgUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labUserName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(imgUser)
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [labUserName, lastMsg ?? UIView()])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        
        let consts = [
            imgUser.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            imgUser.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            imgUser.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            imgUser.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgUser.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(consts)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `let lastMsg : UILabel?` is a constant and requires a value before calling `super.init()`.

Just do `let lastMsg = UILabel()`, and when you don't need it just don't show it, `lastMsg.isHidden = true`.

Comment: is this the best approach, instead of a const i put a var would that work ? and then user has a choice if they want to init it or not

Comment: @testtesting you can put var, and initialise it inside init or after init. Var doesn't have any constraints. But usually you don't have to do that, creating UIViews' is not expensive, if you don't show them in view hierarchy